# Remove a merged repo from the fork repo

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

This is a forked repository and I merged it with the parent repository. But now I want to remove this merge and make 3fdb6f1 commit (the selected one) on the top. It should not say 10 behind. What should I do. I'm using Bitbucket.

[image]

Comment: No. It's the parent repository through which I merged to this forked repository.

Comment: Did you merge it manually? I'm not aware of methods to fork and merge entire repos with Git.

Comment: From bitbucket, it showed that this fork is 10 commits behind the parent repo. So I merged it. And now I want to remove that merge.